# Why rotation with snapping is not working?

Tags: snapping

I am trying to snap edge in edit mode to selected object and can't do it easily though. It only snaps in one view.

I've tried to enable/disable *"Align rotation with snapping target"*, but still without good result:

[image]

I am not looking for other ways like modifiers, etc, because it is quite limited in some cases.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might seem a bit long-winded, but... a variation on this..

1. Set snap to 'Active' and 'Vertex', and in the snap panel, set it to affect rotation
2. Set Pivot to '3D Cursor'
3. Set Transform Orientation to 'View'
4. Establish one end of the snap. With all selected, make the vertex at one end of the source (moving) object active, and snap it to the corresponding end of the target edge. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > send the 3D cursor to the same spot. It will be the center of rotation.
5. Establish the plane of rotation. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate the vertex at the other end of the source object, and snap the duplicate to the other end of the target. With all source vertices selected, <kbd>F</kbd> create a temporary triangular face, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> align the view to the face
6. Delete the duplicate vertex, (and the face, with it)
7. With all source vertices selected, and the loose end vertex active, <kbd>R</kbd> rotate it into place.

This takes longer to describe than it takes to do.. usually there are convenient faces / whatever already hanging around.. you wouldn't have to create them specially, as in this example. Maybe, instead of using the View orientation, you would create a Custom Orientation from a selection of vertices, edges, or faces (either existing, or temporarily created for the purpose).

Comment: Hm, so this snapping design is strictly view dependent? Very strange, that you can move to snap to any point in perspective, but can't with rotation.

Comment: @SergeL No.. snap is _not_ view dependent, but on the whole, it does need to work in the X,Y or Z of a _given_ orientation I only chose the view orientation for 1-off convenience. You could, for example, have created a Custom Orientation from the triangular face, and then, with that orientation active, the command would have been RZ to rotate about the normal of the face, whichever view you were in, and whether or not the face still existed. The orientation is implicit when 'View' is selected, with Z out, X across, Y up, and you can see what you're doing.. but any aligned orientation would do.